# storing each robots.txt value in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

How would someone go about storing each value of a robots.txt value in an array, which can be accessed through the array. Example: website has a robots.txt looking like this:

```
# Comment

Disallow: /link1
Disallow: /abcdefg
Disallow: /fish
Disallow: /salad
```

Skipping the comment, and then storing the text after into an array. So you wont have a value being "Disallow: /link1" but it would be stored as "/link1"

Here is my code (from a tutorial some may know):

```
import urllib.request
import io

def get_robots_txt(url):
    if url.endswith('/'):
        path = url
    else:
        path = url + '/'
    req = urllib.request.urlopen(path + 'robots.txt', data=None)
    data = io.TextIOWrapper(req, encoding='utf-8')
    return data.read()

print(get_robots_txt('http://www.stackoverflow.com'))
input()
```

The above basically takes a URL and stores everything inside the robots.txt and then prints out just as it looks on the website when you go to the robots.txt. What I need is after that to only just store the text after the disallow into an array, so it would ignore the comment (skip first line), then on the third cut out "Disallow: " and store the "/link1" into an array. It would do this after each line and then I would have an array like ["/link1","/abcdefg","/fish","/salad"] sorry if this is specific but I have absolutely no clue how to even start doing something like this. Thanks for everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total = []

for line in lines:

    link = line.split(“ “)[1:]

    total.append(link)
```

That should work. Let me know if that’s not what you were looking  for.

Comment: I edited what i said so it should be more clear now you can message me if I still didn't make it clear as to what is being done

Answer (score 0):

I put the code you wish for into a function so a list is returned and
the local variables are automatically cleaned up.

The function takes the robot string as an argument with an optional
key argument.
It splits the robot string in a list of lines. It then partitions
using `": "` as a separator to return a key, separator and value in
a tuple. It then checks the key as to append the value to the new list
or not. Once loop is done, it returns the new list.

```
def part_robots_txt(robots_txt, key='Disallow'):
    value_list = []
    # Split on '\n' to make a list of lines.
    for line in robots_txt.split('\n'):
        # Part on ': ' to split into (key, sep, value).
        line = line.partition(': ')
        # Check part key with argument key and append to list if True.
        if line[0] == key:
            value_list.append(line[2])
    return value_list

disallow_list = part_robots_txt(data)
print(disallow_list)
```